# Opencv integration with wxpython

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I just wanted to integrate the opencv video stream from my web cam into a more complex gui than highgui can offer, nothing fancy just a couple of buttons and something else, however it's proven to be not that trivial. I can't find any base example from which I can start designing the gui.
I tried converting this [code](https://wxpython-users.googlegroups.com/attach/90dcdd863e015578/cv_webcam.py?view=1&part=2) to the new opencv interface with quite a poor result. I'm a new to opencv, numpy and gui design. Some time does stream the video but most of the time it just hangs there. I guess my one mistake might be in wx.BitmapFromBuffer(col, row, img) since in the older version they used pil image format and now it's using numpy arrays so in the original code the used the pil function "imageData", instead of passing directly the numpy array as I'm doing.
Any help it's really appreciated.
[image: color_channels_pic]

This is my code conversion.

```
import wx
import cv2

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
       self.displayPanel = wx.Panel(self)
       self.displayPanel.SetSize(wx.Size(800,640))

       self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
       self.cam.set(3, 640)
       self.cam.set(4, 480)
       ret, img = self.cam.read()

       cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
       row, col, x = img.shape
       self.SetSize((col,row))
       self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(col, row, img)
       self.displayPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)

       self.playTimer = wx.Timer(self)
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onNextFrame)

       self.playTimer.Start(1000/15)

    def onPaint(self, evt):
        if self.bmp:
            dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.displayPanel)
            self.PrepareDC(dc)
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0, True)
        evt.Skip()

    def onNextFrame(self, evt):
        ret, img = self.cam.read()
        if ret == True:
            cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(img)
            self.displayPanel.Refresh()
        evt.Skip()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, but after minor adjusts it does just fine. The problem I see is that, for example, when I resize the window the stream is interrupted till I stop resizing. But if I don't touch the window it goes on just fine. Are you doing something else beyond simply displaying the frames ?

Comment: @mmgp you're right if I comment the the two lines where I set the size, it works although I guess I'm loosing color channels. I attached the picture.

Comment: regarding colors, `cvtColor` doesn't happen in-place, so you have to reassign its result to `img`.

Comment: @mmgp Right now I'm not performing any other action except for displaying the captured frames, even tough I plan to.

Comment: @mmgp would you please explain it to me in details, because I tough that I was doing what you just told me on every next frame...

Comment: If you have a function `f(x)` that doesn't operate in-place, you have to assign the result to something in order to save the results. `cvtColor` is one such function.

Comment: @mmgp thanks... but btw how can I resize the image as I was doing with set without causing it to crash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following example code works fine for me under OS X, but I've had tiny surprises with wx across platforms. It is nearly the same code, the difference is that the result from `cvtColor` is reassigned, and a subclass of `wx.Panel` (which is the important part) was added.

```
import wx
import cv, cv2

class ShowCapture(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, capture, fps=15):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.capture = capture
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()

        height, width = frame.shape[:2]
        parent.SetSize((width, height))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, frame)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(1000./fps)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.NextFrame)


    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)

    def NextFrame(self, event):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(frame)
            self.Refresh()


capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
cap = ShowCapture(frame, capture)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: why did you subclass panel and not frame? Shouldn't be wx.Frame the first 'container' in the wx hierarchy? And the the second import is not going to work on OSX either I guess since to access the old cv from cv2 you need to import cv2.cv. Your code works on my machine which btw is a linux debian based machine, however it does not set the size frame to 640X480.

Comment: I can import `cv` just fine in OSX. The frame is certainly not set to `640 x 480` because in the example it is set to `320 x 240`, did you try changing that ? A `wx.Frame` is being created, it is the parent of the `wx.Panel` subclassed.

Comment: I tried changing the size, with the new module and the old one, however as soon as I resize it, it doesn't refresh any longer and it starts crashing again.

Comment: By "resize it" do you mean resize the window running the program ? When I resize this window I stop getting updates too, as commented earlier. But it doesn't crash the program. By crash do you mean the program quits ? Maybe the error messages you get could be useful then.

Comment: sorry I didn't make myself clear I meant it became unresponsive and it stops updating itself.

Comment: I get that behavior too, and I'm not sure if that is fixable. Maybe @robindunn can give a tip ? I see that `OnPaint` and `NextFrame` are always being called, but when I leave the mouse button down during the resize (without further resizing), no update actually happens in the panel showing the frames.

Comment: In OS X Yosemite, I was getting an error: `Python quit unexpectedly`. I made the script working by removing `import cv` (keeping only `import cv2`) and removing the last two lines. So I think it might have been an issue with my OpenCV installation.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the size of panel to show the captured image. 
I used your code and I added "

```
self.SetSize(width,height)
```

It's ok

Answer (score 0):

You should add a comment for the below line

```
#self.PrepareDC(dc)
```

It worked for me.