# How to integrate a cv.NamedWindow in a wxpython panel or frame?

Tags: opencv, wxpython

I'm trying to display a continuous feed of cv images in wxpython using cv.NamedWindow and cv.ShowImage methods. However, this opens the NamedWindow as a separate window.

Is there a way to integrate this named window in a wxpython panel or a frame? My requirement is that the NamedWindow should be part of a GUI and not a standalone window.

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804741/opencv-integration-with-wxpython