# Why the SetBitmap function cannot run correctly without imshow function

Tags: opencv, wxpython

I am building an wxPython app, when display every frame by changing the static bitmap image, I got a strange error, my application run normally if I have **imshow()** function in code, if I comment out it, this app only run 1-2 seconds and crash, no error message found, the command screen still show the elapsed time as I printed it.
Here is my code

```
video_capture = VideoStream(0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()

count = 0;

while True:
    frame = video_capture.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=720, height=480)

    t = time.time()

    output_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    self.bitmap_1.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(output_rgb.shape[1], output_rgb.shape[0], output_rgb.tostring()))
    self.Refresh()

    cv2.imshow('Video', output_rgb)
    fps.update()

    print('[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}'.format(time.time() - t))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

fps.stop()
```

Here is initial of bitmap_1

```
self.bitmap_1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.EmptyBitmap(720, 540))
```

Sorry for my bad English, I'm using python 3.6.2

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: It didn't show any error, the program still running but the WX GUI got not response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while`-loop as used in your example will eat 100 % of the CPU time, leaving wxPython no chance to process any event. This is the reason why your app crashes.

You have to get rid of the `while` and have to integrate this part into an event handler of your wxPython app. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14818080/2683116) uses a `wx.Timer` to poll your frame-grabbing routine periodically.

It would be better to put the OpenCV code in a separate thread and transfer the bitmap between the OpenCV thread and the wxPython main thread in a thread-safe manner.

How to spin-off threads in wxPython in general, see [LongRunningTasks](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks),